# Uniform convergence of a sequence of step functions to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $u\in C([a,b];X)$ and $(u_n)$ be a sequence of step functions. For all $n \in \mathbb N$ define $$u_n(t):=u(t_{(k-1)}^{(n)})$$ for $t \in [t_{k-1}^{(n)},t_k^n)$, $k=1,2...,2^n$ and $$u_n(b):=u(t_{2^n-1}^{(n)})$$ where $t_k^{(n)}= a+k \frac{b-a}{2^n}$.

How can I show that $(u_n)$ converges uniformly to $u$ or what is the approach?

Some little help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I claim X to be a metric space,then u is uniformly continous so for a given $\varepsilon > 0$ exists a $\delta > 0$ etc…

$u_n$ converges uniformly to $u$ iff $$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\forall n\ge N: ||u_n - u||_\infty < \varepsilon$$

Take such an $\varepsilon$  and choose N that way, that $\frac{b-a}{2^N} < \delta$ then for $n\ge N$ 
$$\left|u(t_{(k-1)}^{(n)}) - u(t)\right| < \varepsilon$$ for $t \in [t_{k-1}^{(n)},t_k^n) $ so $||u_n - u||_\infty < \varepsilon$

Comment: Thanks a lot, think I will be able to solve it from here on.

Comment: Man it's been a while since I worked with those $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s, how do I get to uniform convergence from uniform continuity? ...

Comment: It's all written in the proof… above you already have $\left|u(t_{(k-1)}^{(n)}) - u(t)\right| < \varepsilon$ for all intervals of your decomposition so you already have $||u_n - u||_\infty < \varepsilon$. Didn't get it?

Comment: Oh yea that was already the proof, on the first sight I thought it was a hint., lol.

Ok just another thing: Why do we have to chose $N$ that way that $\frac{b-a}{2^N} < \delta$? I mean why $\delta<\frac{b-a}{2^N}$

Comment: If the length of the intervals is smaller then $\delta$ you are sure that all values of the function within one intervall have a shorter distance then $\varepsilon$ due to the uniform continuity

Comment: Ah yes, $(a+k\frac{b-2}{2^N}) - (k-1)\frac{b-a}{2^N}= \frac{b-a}{2^N}$...

Thank you, much appreciated.